# open file with window.open and hashtag in filepath/name

Tags: javascript, filepath

I have to use a javascript function that opens a file(jpeg or gif) on the server with window.open(pathtofile).
What can I do to open the file, if it contains a # in the filename?
With  replacing # to %23 it converts the % in the url, so that I have a %2523 and it doesn't work.

Example:

```
var dok = "\\server\Temp\2255699#558.gif";   
window.open(dok);
```

Comment: Take a look at `encodeURIComponent()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: I already tried it with encodeURIComponent(). Then it creats path like http://localhost/test/%5C%5Cserver%5CTemp%5C2255699%23558.gif and it doesn't work

Comment: It is only a part of the solution, you have to apply `encodeURIComponent()` on the part of the path you want to encode. An alternative solution would be to simply use `dok.replace('#', '%23')` and don't forget to escape the '\'.